# Ajuda para otimizar um índice no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, select

Possuo um site de relacionamentos e a anos tento otimizar esta consulta. Quase todos os dias o site trava por causa dela.

Estrutura da tabela de usuários

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `longitude` float(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ano_nascimento` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1997',
  `genero` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `genero_procuro` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `idade_minima` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '18',
  `idade_maxima` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '80',
  `unix_timestamp_online` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `usuario_bloqueado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Índices

```
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD KEY `indice_composto`(
    `unix_timestamp_online`,
    `usuario_bloqueado`,
    `genero`,
    `genero_procuro`,
    `idade_maxima`,
    `idade_minima`,
    `ano_nascimento`,
    `latitude`,
    `longitude`
) USING BTREE;
```

Exemplo de consulta

```
SELECT id, latitude, longitude 
FROM usuarios 
WHERE genero=2 
AND id NOT IN (11111111,2222222) 
AND (ano_nascimento BETWEEN 1961 AND 1999) 
AND (latitude BETWEEN -25.14 AND -16.13) 
AND (longitude BETWEEN -54.87 AND -45.86) 
AND usuario_bloqueado=0 
AND idade_minima<=35 
AND idade_maxima>=35 
AND genero_procuro IN(0,1) 
ORDER BY unix_timestamp_online DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Resumindo as condições da consulta de exemplo..

- Sou `masculino=1` e estou procurando usuários do gênero `feminino=2`
- Excluo alguns `ids`
- Nasceram entre `1961 AND 1999`
- Estão em `latitude`, `longitude`...
- Não possuem nenhum tipo de `bloqueio=0`
- Minha `idade=35` precisa ser aceitável por estes usuários
- Meu gênero também precisa ser aceitável (`todos=0`, masculino=1)
- Ordeno exibindo usuários que estão online primeiro

Acredito que o índice composto que foi criado não seja tão bonito, mas de todas as formas que tentei, essa foi a que menos trouxe consultas lentas. 
Tem consulta que leva menos de 1 segundo, outra leva 4, outra 10, 20 e assim por diante. É difícil informar o que eu já tentei, pois foram quase todas as combinações de índices...
Posso estar errando em apenas um detalhe, no índice, no select, talvez precise procurar outro banco, não sei, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda. Obrigado.

**EDITADO:**

Explain da consulta de exemplo

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: usuarios
partitions: NULL
type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY
key: indice_composto
key_len: 19
ref: NULL
rows: 20
filtered: 0.25
Extra: Using where; Using index
```

Esta consulta leva em média de 0.0020 segundos

Se eu alterar a condição ano_nascimento para (`ano_nascimento BETWEEN 1999 AND 1999`)

O explain é idêntico e a consulta leva em média de 9.1376 segundos

Comment: Quantos registos tem a tabela usuarios?

Comment: acredito que deveria criar um indice para cada coluna usada no filtro, e não um índice composto com todas as colunas

Comment: Se a coluna unix_timestamp_online somente é usado para ordenação e não para filtro, eu removeria ela do índice. Índices são basicamente para agilizar o acesso ao registro, não para ordenação.

Comment: Olá Isac. A tabela possui 3 milhões de registros.

Comment: Murillo, e quando a busca no banco encontra muitos registros para retornar? Não vai precisar de um índice na coluna de ordenação para agilizar a exibição dos 20 registros?

Comment: pode colar a saída do comando `explain extended` do seu `select`?

Comment: Olá Bruno, desculpe, eu devia ter colado o explain na hora da criação. Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Rovann, quando eu crio um índice para cada coluna, muitas vezes o otimizador insiste em usar o índice de ordenação e a consulta fica lenta, se eu remover o índice de ordenação, ele usa a chave primária como índice e a consulta leva mais de 20 segundos.